Issues with Full Content Fetching in WordPress RSS Aggregator for a Valid RSS Feed
I recently created an RSS feed available at rss-feed-metakam-resourceworks.vercel.app/feed.rss. After validation through validator.w3.org/feed, it was confirmed that the RSS is valid. However, I am facing an issue with the WordPress RSS aggregator not pulling the full content of the feed.
When I activate the [Force full content] option in the aggregator settings, it fails and reports that it "cannot feed the rss". This is confusing especially since the feed passes the validation without any problems.
Here are the steps I’ve taken so far:

Validated the RSS feed using the W3C validator.
Attempted to pull the feed into WordPress using the standard RSS widget as well as other popular RSS plugins.
Enabled [Force full content] option in the aggregator settings, which resulted in errors.

Is there something specific within the RSS structure that could cause this issue in WordPress only, despite the feed being valid? Or could this be related to how WordPress processes the RSS feed?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
